Why does $-\Delta + w$ have compact resolvent?
Let $\Delta$ be the usual Laplacian on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ and $w: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ be such that $\lim_{|x|\to \infty}w(x) = \infty$. Suppose further that $w \in L^{p}_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ for $p > \max\{n/2,1\}$. The function $w$ acts as a multiplication operator. I want to prove that $-\Delta + w$ has compact resolvent. Is there a simple proof of this result? I was trying to use the min-max principle. My idea was to assume that the the limiting min-max value of $-\Delta + w$, denoted by $\mu_{\infty}$ is finite, i.e. $\mu_{\infty} < \infty$. Then, it is an element of the essential spectrum of $-\Delta+w$, so that there is a sequence $\{\psi_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ functions with $\|\psi_{n}\| = 1$ and such that $\|(-\Delta+w - \mu_{\infty})\psi_{n}\| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. However, I could not conclude the argument.

Some comments: 1) You don't need $w\in L^p_{\mathrm{loc}}$ for $p>\max{n/2,1}$. It suffices to assume $w\in L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}$. You can also relax the growth condition. 2) A self-adjoint operator with compact resolvent has empty essential spectrum, so your approach cannot work. In fact, that's an equivalence (i.e. empty essential spectrum if and only if compact resolvent). 3) A nice proof of this result is in Barry Simon's paper "Schrödinger operators with purely discrete spectrum". For quite some time I wanted to sketch the argument for some other question here (which I don't find ...[1/2]

[2/2] ... at the moment). So if you posted an answer with a proof sketch, that would be very much appreciated.

MaoWao many thanks for the comments and the reference. I will take a look. Let me just comment on my proof strategy. The idea was to prove it by absurd. So assuming there is a Weyl sequence as I posted and then proving that $\langle \psi_{n}, (-\Delta+w)\psi_{n}\rangle$ does not go to zero as $n \to \infty$. I think the proof should work, but I was not able to finish it yet.

MaoWao, I posted an answer with my thoughts. I still was not able to finish the proof, but I think I am really close to it. It is just a matter of refining the final argument I guess.

This is not a definite answer, but I am almost there! I am still following the strategy of the post. Let $\mu_{\infty}$ be the limiting min-max value of $H = -\Delta + w$ and suppose by absurd that $\mu_{\infty} < \infty$. Because $\mu_{\infty}$ is an accumulation point of $\sigma(H)$ then $\mu_{\infty} \in \sigma_{\text{ess}}(H)$. Then, there exists a sequence $\{\psi_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ functions with $\|\psi_{n}\| =1$ and such that $\|(H-\mu_{\infty})\psi_{n}\| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Thus, we can find a constant $C>0$ such that $\|(H-\mu_{\infty})\psi_{n}\| \le C$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
We now note that:
$$\langle \psi_{n}, (H-\mu_{\infty})\psi_{n}\rangle \le \|\psi_{n}\|\|(H-\mu_{\infty})\psi_{n}\| = \|(H-\mu_{\infty})\psi_{n}\| \le C. \tag{1}\label{1}$$
Furthermore, because $-\Delta$ is a positive operator, we have:
$$\langle \psi_{n}, w\psi_{n}\rangle \le \langle \psi_{n},w\psi_{n}\rangle + \langle \psi_{n},-\Delta\psi_{n}\rangle \le C+ \mu_{\infty} \tag{2}\label{2}$$
by (\ref{1}).
From this, we see that:
$$\langle \psi_{n},-\Delta\psi_{n}\rangle \le 2C+2\mu_{\infty}.\tag{3}\label{3}$$
Consequently, each $\psi_{n}$ is $H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ bounded because $\|\psi_{n}\|_{H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})} := \|\psi_{n}\|^{2}+\|\nabla \psi_{n}\|^{2} \le 1+ (2C+2\mu_{\infty})^{2}$. By the Sobolev inequality for $H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, we conclude that $\psi_{n} \in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ for $2 \le p \le p^{*} = 2n/(n-2)$.
Now, we have:
$$\langle \psi_{n}, H\psi_{n}\rangle \ge \langle \psi_{n}, -\Delta \psi_{n} + \langle \psi_{n}, w\psi_{n}\rangle \ge \int w(x)|\psi_{n}(x)|^{2}dx. \tag{4}\label{4}$$
We now write:
$$\int w(x)|\psi_{n}(x)|^{2}dx = \int_{|x| \le R}w(x)|\psi_{n}(x)|^{2} + \int_{|x| > R}w(x)|\psi_{n}(x)|^{2}$$
for some $R > 0$ sufficiently large. On one hand:
$$\int_{|x|\le R}w(x)|\psi_{n}(x)|^{2} \ge - \|w\|_{L^{p}}\|\psi_{n}\|_{L^{q}} \ge -C\|w\|_{L^{p}}, \tag{5}\label{5}$$
for some constant $C > 0$. On the other hand:
$$\int_{|x|> R}w(x)|\psi_{n}(x)|^{2} \ge \inf_{|x|>R}w(x)\int_{|x|>R}|\psi_{n}(x)|^{2} \ge \inf_{|x|>R}w(x)\|\psi_{n}\|_{L^{2}} $$
Now, I need to prove that this latter integral goes to infinity in the limits $n \to \infty$ and $R \to \infty$, so I get a contradiction with the fact that $\mu_{\infty} < \infty$. I know that $\lim_{R \to \infty}\inf_{|x| \ge R}w(x) = \infty$; however, $\int_{|x|\ge R}|\psi_{n}(x)|^{2} \to 0$ as $R \to \infty$, so I can't finish the argument.
